# Проблема с графиком matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Возник вопрос по графику в matplotlib. Есть датасет автомобилей. Тип данных в последних колонках "numpy.float64", решил построить графики. С первым графиком всё нормально, а со вторым нет. Что здесь может быть не так? Почему ось абсцисс принимает такой вид? Price и Mileage отсортировал и сделал массивами numpy, с первым всё нормально, со вторым получается не то. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: График цен на модели авто, Price - отсортированный массив numpy, здесь всё нормально]

[image: График пробега на модели авто, Mileage - отсортированный массив numpy, здесь проблема в оси x]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в данных присутствует **выброс**, то есть значение, сильно отличающееся от остальных. Из-за этого график сильно сжался там, где расположено большинство (нормальных) значений. Откуда этот выброс там взялся, соответствует ли он действительности - это отдельный вопрос, от решения которого зависит, что с этим делать. Промоделируем ситуацию:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import random

model = list(range(2100, 2200))
mileage = list(range(100_000, 200_000, 1000))
random.shuffle(mileage)
mileage[50] = 1_000_000
df = pd.DataFrame({'Model': model, 'Mileage': mileage})
plt.scatter(df['Mileage'], df['Model']);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самое простое, что можно сделать - просто удалить выбросы, например, взяв 99% квантиль:

```
tmp = df[df['Mileage'] < df['Mileage'].quantile(0.99)]
plt.scatter(tmp['Mileage'], tmp['Model']);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом выбросы можно нарисовать на отдельном графике:

```
tmp = df[df['Mileage'] >= df['Mileage'].quantile(0.99)]
plt.scatter(tmp['Mileage'], tmp['Model']);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вообще выбросы - это довольно интересная тема и в общем случае вопрос происхождения выбросов обычно требует более тщательного изучения. Но в случае, если просто хочется посмотреть нормально график, удаление выбросов - вполне допустимая практика.